# Can I replace $ by $('form')?

Tags: jquery-validate

I use this https://jsfiddle.net/rz0zk5u6/2/ to validate 2 forms on the same page.

To differentiate the forms, can I replace

```
$.validator.setDefaults({});
```

by

```
$("#loginForm").validator.setDefaults({});
```

?

Comment: You can use `$("form").validator`.This selector will be to select all forms, independs of names or ids.

Comment: Oops, yes I wanted to say : $("#loginForm").validator.setDefaults({}); with the # obviously !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.validator.setDefaults({});
```

is for setting the global defaults. If you wish to set per-form options, use:

```
var loginForm = $('#loginForm').validate({
  // options go here
});
```

as [described in the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate). Then you can use:

```
loginForm.form();
```

to perform the validation as [described here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/).

Comment: So you mean I can put the "setDefaults" content into the validate() function, after the rules ?

Comment: @Xavier Yes. [This](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/) says they accept the same options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jquery plugins will apply to elements in a selection/jquery object. If you select multiple forms, it will apply the validator to all of them. The following all do the same thing; Apply the validator to multiple forms.

```
$('form').validator.setDefaults({});
$('#loginForm, #anotherForm').validator.setDefaults({});
var forms = $('form');
forms.validator.setDefaults({});
```

Comment: Okay, but wait! Why this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefaults' of undefined" ?

Comment: Because whatever your validator plugin is doesn't have a `setDefaults()` method when applied like that.